# Intersect parabola with rotated plane in 3D engine

Tags: math, 3d

I am currently writing my own gravity simulation in a 3D engine. I am trying to find out where an object is going to hit another, and that means that I have a parabola (quadratic function) that returns the y position over time.

The ABC formula is a correct way to do this but to my knowledge it is not possible to use this if a 3rd dimension is added to the simulation.

The function returns a position on time t based on the start position, velocity and gravitational constant.

Comment: In your ideal case you would have start position, velocity and acceleration for x, y and z? And your ground plane is not necessarily orthogonal to the z-axis right?

Comment: I do have an initial position, velocity and acceleration. The ground plane should be able to have any orientation. The start position, velocity and acceleration are all vectors which consist of a x, y and z component. However, ABC formula only works on a 2D plane (or Z position always being 0) and I'm unsure how to calculate where a sphere would hit the plane if none of the velocity components are 0.

Comment: The gravity direction is always along -z?

Comment: No the gravity is along the Y axis. Gravity is defined as Vector3(0,-9.81f,0), but in the future I might make support for additional axes

Comment: Why don't just solve the ODE numerically? I think is way more robust and easier to add more features in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think I actually found my problem. Here's the explanation:
[image: Explanation]
<sub>(source: [rubensrv.nl](http://ss.rubensrv.nl/i/1382Ww.png))</sub>